# Why is an empty array greater than any number?

Tags: php, arrays

Could someone explain what happens under the hood in PHP when it compares an empty array with any number and returns `true`?

```
var_dump([] > -1); // true
var_dump([] > 0); // true
var_dump([] > 222222222) // true
```

I tested this in PHP 7.0, 7.1 and 5.6.

Comment: The question is why would you compare an array and a number?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, please never do this kind of comparison; code that does this is highly suspect and probably very broken.

To answer your question: the reason is that comparison of an array to a non-array has a defined behavior as [set out in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types). The array is always greater than any scalar value to which it is compared. Objects are always greater than arrays, and arrays are always greater than scalars (such as integers). Other comparisons are handled in a variety of ways, as defined in the docs.

From the docs:

> ## Comparison with Various Types
>
> ```
> Type of Operand 1    Type of Operand 2    Result
> ...
> array                anything             array is always greater
> ```

Some sample code and a [demo](https://3v4l.org/7OmoO):

```
var_dump(
    [] > -1, //true
    [] > 0, // true
    [] > 222222222, // true
    [] > [], // false, obviously
    [] > new stdClass(), //false, object wins
    new stdClass() > [] // true, object wins
    );
```

Comment: Regarding using this kind of comparison in real life I absolutely agree with you, and I haven't ever used it in prod. What I was worried about was if php made some sort of type juggling, but looks like this is a strict rule, that we must rely on. Anyway, thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types):

> array is always greater